# who is setting my link_power_management_policy?

Tags: electrical-power, sata

I am experiencing issues with my sata connection.
Thus, I want to change `/sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy` to max_performance.

For that, I execute on boot a script:

```
cat /etc/openmediavault/sata_power.sh
for i in /sys/class/scsi_host/host[012345]/link_power_management_policy; do echo max_performance >$i; done
cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy
```

I see that this script is running and also the output is max_performance (I get the output by mail).

Nevertheless, if I log in to the machine after boot, I get `med_power_with_dipm` for all hosts.

Who is changing that setting?

The only other file that I find in /etc that includes power_management_policy is

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/hd_power_save.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", KERNEL=="host*", ATTR{link_power_management_policy}="max_performance"
```

Best regards,
Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a kernel default. From the [docs:](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/disks.html#sata-linkpwr-on-ac-bat)

> med_power_with_dipm – best balance between power saving and performance (Kernel ≥ 4.15 required, then recommended)

> Default when unconfigured: “med_power_with_dipm max_performance” (AC), “med_power_with_dipm min_power” (BAT)

Comment: That is the default of TLP. But I have uninstalled TLP. Indeed, this has changed the situation. Now, After Boot I have min_power. This although I have a crontab entry that sets it to max_power (see above) at Boot. The problem is, that I have SATA Errors already during the boot. I would like to rule out this setting. Thus, I need to ensure that already during boot the setting is max_power.

Comment: Try adding the following kernel boot option: `libata.force=nolpm`